# Derivative of a Linear Model wrt x

Tags: regression, standard-error, error-propagation, derivative

I have a linear model that I want to take derivatives of in order to perform inference. Does anyone know, or can direct me, to information on the standard errors of the derivatives? For instance, if the model is $y=b+b_1x^2$, where $b_1$ has an estimate of 3 and a standard error of 2, then what is the standard error of the derivative of that term, $2*b_1*x$?

Thoughts: If $b_1$ is a random variable, then the fact that we are taking derivatives wrt $x$ doesn't change anything, the constant in front of $x$ would just have mean $2*3=6$ and standard error $\sqrt{2^2*2^2}=4$. Where I used $Var(2*b_1)=4*Var(b_1)=4*4=16$ then $SD(2*b_1) = 4$. Is this along the right path?

Follow up question: How about the distribution of the derivative of a predictive distribution?

Comment: Why are you squaring coefficients twice?  The rule is a simple consequence of tracking units of measure: when a random variable $b$ has a standard error $s,$ the SE of any multiple $\lambda b$ is just $|\lambda|s.$

Comment: I took the long way through variance, but the result is the same. The question is, can I do derivatives like that?

Comment: You invoke a basic rule of differentiation in your question: the derivative of a constant times a function is the constant times the derivative of the function.  Is that what your comment is referring to?  If so, the answer clearly is yes.